# Removing Browser Readonly Styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to disable user text input in a text field, and am using the `readonly="true"` attribute on the input itself.

However, I don't want it too look different then a default input field. I'm am trying to write a solution that will not make me go in and write CSS for it, as browsers may change their styling and make this miserable.

Is there any way to just remove the browsers `readonly` style?

Here's a screenshot I'm talking about. The one on the right is `readonly`, but I want it to look the same as the one on the left.[image: This is only in Chrome. All browsers will handle it differently.]

Comment: You could manually set the styles of the input to be the same as something that isn't read only. 

This example (http://jsfiddle.net/2C85E/) shows how to target something that is read only

Comment: This is great -- but would there be any way to just override the browsers readonly styles and replace them with the default input styles? I'm trying to avoid putting styles on all inputs and readonlys to make them look the same.

Comment: Just add seven days to the one on the left, and they will be the same ;-) ....

Comment: @adeneo, lol. I was referring to the input's styling, not it's contents :)

Comment: @streetlight I don't think so, all browsers manage things like inputs differently to try and improve the UEx, there isn't really a "default" input style defined, just what the browsers want to do :(

Comment: The way to do it is with CSS like Andy showed. It's just two lines of CSS to fix your problem. No other changes on site needed. Doesn't get much easier.

Comment: Worth noting that [readonly="true"] selector wont work in IE

Comment: How does this appear to you? http://jsfiddle.net/am_d/2C85E/1/

This is an amended version of @Andy's fiddle, they look exactly the same to me in FF and IE9 (update: and Chrome and Opera). Maybe you could specify all the label and text styles once where Andy put bg red?

Comment: Honestly this is just a bad usability idea from the get go. Browsers display disabled controls differently for a REASON, people expect a control that looks like an enabled control to be accessible. It is very very bad web design to change things like this.

Comment: @RickCalder, I agree with you, but perhaps I wasn't clear with the end result of this entire process. I am trying to give readonly functionality to a field using jQueryUI Datepicker, so the user can't type into the field themselves, but only use the datepicker field. The most efficent way I found was to place readonly on the input, cutting down on as much code as possible.

Comment: Yeah I understand that and I've done that on a number of occasions, my argument is trying to make the box not look disabled is defeating the purpose of UI visual cues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser styles are by definition browser-specific, so any solution would be browser-specific. You would need to study the browser defaults (from documentation or via experimentation) and to serve different styles to different browsers. A lot of work, and I don’t quite see what the potential benefit might be. It would in general be bad for usability to remove the distinction between normal and disabled fields.

You can set the style explicitly to be the same for normal and disabled fields, but then you won’t get browser defaults.